# (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: discord, discord.js, command, bots

I just made a check vouches command in discord.js, but when I try it I keep getting this error

```
const db = require('quick.db')

module.exports = {
    name: 'vouches',
    description: 'Check Someones Vouches!',
    async execute(message, args, client) {
        let user = message.mentions.members.first()
        if(!user) return user = message.author;
        let vouch = db.fetch(`vouch_${message.user.id}`)
        if(vouch === null) vouch = 0
        
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#0099ff')
            .setTitle(`${message.user.username}'s vouches`)
            .setDescription(`:money_with_wings:You currently have ${vouch} vouches:money_with_wings:`)        
            message.channel.send(embed);
    },
};
```

this is my command ^^
This is my error:

```
2021-04-29T15:57:02.870113+00:00 app[Worker.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
2021-04-29T15:57:02.870134+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Object.execute (/app/commands/vouches.js:10:52)
2021-04-29T15:57:02.870135+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Object.execute (/app/events/MessageEvent.js:79:21)
2021-04-29T15:57:02.870136+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
2021-04-29T15:57:02.870254+00:00 app[Worker.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
```

Comment: That's your code, not your error. Can you post the full error?

Comment: `message.user` is not a property, I believe you mean to use `message.author`